# Get all value from pagination REST

Tags: java, rest, pagination

It is possible to get all value from pagination REST? For example I have the REST:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/divisions", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Division>> getAllDivisions(Pageable pageable)
    throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Divisions");
    Page<Division> page = divisionRepository.findAll(pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/divisions");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But in my application I need getting all divisions. I tried something like this: 
http://localhost:9000/api/divisions?size=MAX but it doesn't work.
Do I have to create new REST for this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in all probability, the DB and driver you are using returns page of Division content which must have a set page size.

In your case, either you parse the query  parameter 'size' with value 'MAX', in case when size is MAX, you need to call findAll method in a loop till you get all the pages and in the loop keep adding those pages content to a list, which in the end you will return.

How do you get all page depends on your driver, for example in case of DynamoDB there was a way to fetch the last id of a page content and use that id to get next page content. Without the specifics it's difficult to chart out an efficient way.